# MySQL query really slow as loading benchmark

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm experiencing a very slow loading benchmark from this MySQL query with some `WHERE` and `HAVING` conditions:

```
  SELECT * FROM test p 
  WHERE p.brandid=636  
    AND DATEDIFF(p.registration, '2019-01-01') >= 0 
    AND DATEDIFF(p.registration, '2019-05-22') <= 0  
  GROUP BY p.invoice_num 
  HAVING (p.net_amount BETWEEN 0 AND 1000) 
    AND (p.profit_amount BETWEEN 0 AND 1000) 
    AND (p.cost_amount BETWEEN 0 AND 1000) 
  ORDER BY p.registration DESC LIMIT 100 OFFSET 0
```

Below the CREATE STMT:

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `id` bigint(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `original_id` bigint(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `invoice_num` bigint(11) NOT NULL,
  `registration` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `paid_amount` decimal(10,6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cost_amount` decimal(10,6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `profit_amount` decimal(10,6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `net_amount` decimal(10,6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `customer_id` bigint(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `recipient_id` text,
  `cashier_name` text,
  `sales_type` text,
  `sales_status` text,
  `sales_location` text,
  `invoice_duration` text,
  `store_id` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_cash` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_card` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `brandid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`invoice_num`),
  KEY `idx_registration_compound` (`id`,`registration`),
  KEY `invoiceNum_idx` (`invoice_num`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=47420958 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I have added a compound index between `id` and `registration` fields. But I think that I could improve it with a more correct combination of indexes.

Below the EXPLAIN:
[image]

Is the **TIMEDIFF()** a problem for the performance?
Any ideas of how to improve the benchmark?

Comment: Add an index on `brandid` and you could change the date condition to `between` clause and see the performance.

Comment: DATEDIFF will cause problems for performance as it is forcing a function call for each comparison. And you could just compare the dates directly without the function calls. But your query doesn't appear to make much sense as far as using HAVING. You are grouping by invoice_num and then checking field values within the HAVING clause without using aggregate functions. Assuming invoice_num isn't unique you could have multiple rows, with MySQL chosing values from an indeterminant matching row. So you could have a row that passes the HAVING conditions, but isn't selected as dropped by the GROUP BY.

Answer (score 2):

Your where clause  involve the column brandid (p.brandid=636)  and p.registration (DATEDIFF(p.registration, '2019-01-01'))  so try add  add a composite index  on

```
table  test  columns  ( brandid, registration)
```

Answer (score 1):

as suggested create a composite index  using ( brandid, registration)  and

**try to run with force index with newly created composite index**

logically your query can be reframed as

```
SELECT * FROM test p force index (index_name)
  WHERE p.brandid=636  
    AND p.registration between  '2019-01-01' and '2019-05-22'
  GROUP BY p.invoice_num 
  HAVING (p.net_amount BETWEEN 0 AND 1000) 
    AND (p.profit_amount BETWEEN 0 AND 1000) 
    AND (p.cost_amount BETWEEN 0 AND 1000) 
  ORDER BY p.registration DESC LIMIT 100 OFFSET 0
```

**try running this and share the explain result set**

Comment: your rows count was reduced from 43012777 to 13685994. but only the registration index key is used. try force use the newly created